# Saving an image directly to _variant_t

Tags: visual-c++, com, gdi+

I need to store the GDI+ bitmap image bytes into `_variant_t`. I can [save the image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ms535406(v=vs.85)) to `IStream` (created by `SHCreateMemStream`), and I can then copy the stream's contents to a buffer created with `SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1,...)`. But this means at certain time I will have the same byte array twice in memory. It works, but I'm wondering if there is some SIMPLE way to have only one buffer in memory. Maybe there is some "SafeArrayStream" unknown to me that I can use instead of memory stream (I sure don't wish to make one myself). Or maybe there is a way to figure out required buffer size before calling on `Image::Save`.

The `_variant_t` that I create is then consumed by a third-party library. It probably makes a third copy of the buffer, but I have no control over that.

Comment: You can define a VARIANT to contain an IUnknown pointer (VT_UKNOWN). For the _variant_t there is an operator. I don't remember if this works cross apartment/process (IStream may be known to ole/aut) , but this is pretty safe in the same apartment.

Comment: I tried it but the mentioned third-party library does not recognize IStream. My guess it only works with safe array of VT_UI1.

Comment: Oh, if you use a 3rd party that only understands a restricted set of VARIANTs, then there's no question.